# Send emails from several email forms to several email addresses

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email, contacts

I have a email system on my website, people can send me emails by completing a form. On the website i have 2 different forms and the JS (contact_me.js) and the PHP (contact_me.php) that make those email forms work. Now i receive emails from both email forms on the same email address but i want to change that, when someone send me a email from the 2nd email form i want to receive that email on the 2nd email address. I am planning to copy/paste the JS and the PHP and call them contact_her.js and contact_her.php and than connect the 2nd email form to the 2nd email address. I am new at JS, can someone identify the things that i have to modify in the JS and HTML to make this happen? Here is the code:

HTML:

```
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message and the delivery address."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();

        // this is where you're getting your message text
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();

        // add in the childNodes code
        var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('tag');
        var tagText = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            tagText += tags[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ' ';
        }
        // trim the trailing whitespace
        tagText = tagText.trim();

        // add the message body and the tag text together:
        message = message + '\n\nOrdered products codes: ' + tagText;






        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');


                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                $('.tag').remove();



            },
            error: function () {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later or send a email yourself at order@o-p-a-l.eu");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function () {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function () {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'email1@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: email1@gmail.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your question:

> when someone send me a email from the 2nd email form i want to receive that email on the 2nd email address

One way you can do this is to send a variable to your data to specify which form your are sending from:

```
data: {
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
    email: email,
    message: message,
    form: 'form1'
},
```

The value `form1` can be stored/retrieved in many ways.  One such way would be to include it in the name:

```
<form name="form1">
```

Then, in javascript, you can retrieve the value of the form name like:

```
var myForm = $('#whatEverYourFormIdIs').attr('name');
```

Then, update your contact_me.php script to check the value of `form` property from JSON and update your email TO accordingly.

The other way would be to changet the `$.ajax({url})` property depending on which form your are submitting.

Comment: And in HTML 'form1' will be the id of the form or the name? and how do i make the PHP to check the valu of form? :D

Comment: You can store the value of the form you are submitting in either a hidden field, a data attribute, or in the form tag itself as it's name or ID.  I have updated my answer with the name option.  To check the value, just add it to your POST object (as shown above) and check the value of `$_POST['form']`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a hidden field in the form like

```
<input type="hidden" name="targetEmail" value="email1">
```

and pass that to the server, that way the server will know what email to send the form contents to.

Comment: Good contribution, but I would advise against this because the value of the hidden field could be changed thus enabling a malicious user to send the email to whomever they wished.  In my answer above, you can control  where the email gets sent.

Comment: You can change the value in both cases. There's no perfect solution for this as it comes from the front end directly.

Comment: Respectfully disagree; the email address that it sends to doesn't come from the front end in my solution.  It is a hardcoded value on the backend, only determined by the string value of the `form` property that is deserialized from JSON.

Comment: @user1477388 oh, maybe I didn't make the answer clear :) by saying email1 i meant some sort of variable to be decoded by server into an email :)) Yes putting plain email in there would not be a good solution at all!